# Not able to detect my IE 11 Browser

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser

I am trying to write an IE specific code which

```
    if (agent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1)
    {
        alert('IE');
        //IE specific
    }
```

But when I tried 
alert(agent.indexOf("MSIE"));
It printed -1.
But I am able to get my current browser properly using agent.indexOf() in Firefox and Chrome successfully.

Can anyone help me out with writing browser specific code?
I checked out previous questions based on Browser specific code but none helped.
The issue is occurred in IE 11 version 11.0.24 and also 11.0.25.
Thank you.

Comment: This might help: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh869301(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Use feature detection, not browser string magic!

Comment: It would be nice to know in what way the code is going to be IE specific?

Answer (score 1):

I believe only IE supports `ActiveXObject`, though there may be some extensions out there that give other browsers some kind of support, and as long as it enabled in the browser then you could do. Probably more accurate than testing the user agent, which can be easily changed. You could even combine multiple feature tests, I'm pretty sure that there are others that are only supported by IE.

`if ('ActiveXObject' in window) {
  alert('IE');
}`

Comment: Thank you @Xotic750 . ActiveXObject worked for me.But Could you explain me how does it work?

Comment: It's an object on `window` and is a Microsoft only object, and so is only present on Internet Explorer browsers.